# Convert Parse Token Curl to Ajax

Tags: ajax, curl, parse-platform, token

I need to convert this to ajax.

```
curl -X POST \
                    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ****************" \
                    -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ******************" \
                    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                    -d '{
                            "deviceType": "ios",
                            "deviceToken": "result" ,
                            "channels": [
                                ""
                                    ]
                        }' \
                        https://api.parse.com/1/installations
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is to create an ajax post method. So in this example, you would do the following ajax method.

```
var headers = {
   "X-Parse-Application-Id":"Your ID", 
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key":"Your Rest API Key"
        };
    // Convert data object to JSON string:
var userData = { "deviceType": "the device or the variable that says the device",
                 "deviceToken": "The Token itself or the variable with the token",
                 "channels": [""]
               };
var data = JSON.stringify(userData);


   $.ajax({
        headers: headers,
        type: 'POST',
        url: "https://api.parse.com/1/installations",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: data,
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data) {

        // We log the responce from the server just to check.
        alert("data:" + JSON.stringify(data) + " status: " + status); 

        },
        error:function(data) {

        // Show error message:
        alert("Your data didn't save!" + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        });
```